# How do I create a frame around an entire section, so that it doesn't eat up my table?

Tags: mdframed

used mdframe for 1st and it worked, and in the second it eats it up.

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass [10pt]{ article}
\usepackage[utf8]{ inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ctg}{ctg}
\title{LaTeX vježbe-5}
\author{Dino Luinović}
\date{30.10.2017}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \newtheorem{zadatak}{Zadatak}[section]
    \begin{mdframed}
    \section{Derivacija}
    \subsection{Tehnika deriviranja}

    \textbf{Definicija:} Neka je $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ funkcija, $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ otvoreni interval i $c\in I$.Kažemo da je $f$ derivabilna u $c$ ako postoji\\
    \begin{equation}\label{derlim}
    \lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\\
    \end{equation}
    i taj limes označimo s $f'(c).$

    \begin{zadatak}
        Koristeći definiciju $\left( {\color{red}\ref{derlim}} \right)$, 
        odredite derivaciju funkcije $ f(x)= \cos(x).$  
    \end{zadatak}
    \textbf{Rješenje:}\\
    \begin{align*}
    f'(c) & = \lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\\
    & = \lim_{x \to c}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(c)}{x-c}\\
    & = \lim_{x \to c}\frac{-2\sin(\frac{x+c}{2})\sin(\frac{x-c}{2})}{x-c}\\
    & = -\sin c
    \end{align*}\\

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[DZ:] Neka je $f(x)= \ln\left(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\right)$. Odredite:
        \item[(a)] domenu funkcije $f$
        \item[(b)] intervale monotonosti i ekstreme.
    \end{itemize}

\end{mdframed}

    \newpage
    \begin{mdframed}

    \section{Integral}
    \subsection{Tablica Integrala}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Integrali}
        \label{tab1}
        \begin{tabular}{|l | l| c|}
            \hline
            $\int\ dx = x + C$ & $\int\frac{\,dx}{\cos^2 x}=\tg x + C$\\
            \hline
            $\int\ x^a {\,dx}=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} + \ +C (a \neq -1)$
            &$\int\frac{\,dx}{\sin^2 x}=-\ctg x+\ C$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Tablica $\left( {\color{red}\ref{tab1}} \right)$ prikazuje integrale nekih funkcija.

\end{mdframed}



    \section{Red}
    \subsection{Taylorovi redovi}
    U ovom području se zadaju naredbe za treću sekciju.
    \section{Matrice}
    A ovdje pišemo naredbe za sekciju Matrice.


\end{document}
```